# I want to insert into table with column data in a gap of 1000

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with data like:
[image]

Now, I want to insert data into a new table but with the div_number in gaps of 1000. like 0,1000,2000,3000 etc:

If the table is having existing data, then, i have to add further blocks with higher block size.
[image]

But, when I query the data from table, I got gap of more than 1000 because suppose there is no data available between  3000-4000. and the block is not created for that.
[image]

How can I get the result I want from the selected table?
Can anyone please help me with the query?

Answer (score 0):

`DIV_NUMB` values have to be *brand new*, they don't have anything in common with what you want to get.

If you *know* that you'd want to start with 2000, then

```
SQL> select 1000 + 1000 * row_number() over (order by t.datum, t.div_numb) div_numb,
  2    t.datum
  3  from test t
  4  order by t.datum, t.div_numb;

  DIV_NUMB DATUM
---------- ----------
      2000 01.04.2020
      3000 01.04.2020
      4000 01.04.2020
      5000 08.04.2020

SQL>
```

If starting point has to be calculated, then it gets more complicated, e.g.

```
SQL> with mdn (div_numb, gap) as
  2    (select (trunc(min(div_numb) / 1000) * 1000) - 1000,
  3            1000
  4     from test)
  5  select
  6    (m.div_numb * row_number() over (order by t.datum, t.div_numb)) + m.gap div_Numb,
  7    t.datum
  8  from mdn m cross join test t;

  DIV_NUMB DATUM
---------- ----------
      2000 01.04.2020
      3000 01.04.2020
      4000 01.04.2020
      5000 08.04.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the source table is not having data for 4000&5000. How can it get selected here?

Comment: You're welcome. If it doesn't exist, you have to make it (as my queries show). Though, maybe I don't understand the question ...

Comment: I understand the query you have created. But I have approx 100,000 rows in source table having duplicate div_numb. But in the destination table, I have to add the rows only once.

Comment: Duplicate DIV_NUMB? That's not what your sample data (posted in original question) show. There are duplicate DATE values. Please, edit the question and post what you really have and what you'd want to get. Because, it's just too much guessing.